# Help passing objects to methods in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, modelbinders

I have this snippet in my html... Fusion Charts requires I feed it an XML to create a graph

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myChart = new FusionCharts("/Content/Fusion_Charts/Charts/Column3D.swf", "myChartId", "470", "350", "0", "0");
        myChart.setDataURL("/XML/Graph/?list=<%=Model.list%>");
        myChart.render("Graph");
    </script>
```

So in my XMLController I simply have a method like this

```
public ActionResult Graph(FusionChartsList list)
        {
            return View(list);
        }
```

So my question is... how can I get the object to actually populate when passing it as url parameter??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call the [`setDataXML` Javascript method](http://www.fusioncharts.com/Docs/Contents/JS_setDataXML.html) with the raw XML string instead.

Comment: I dont like that approach cause Im using this particular graph in several places... thats the reason why I created an XML Controller, so that I can generate the XML depending on the data it receives... the data is constructed in the particular Controllers and then sent to this Controller to actually make the XML

Comment: Why don't you call `RenderAction`?  (Make sure to escape the Javascript string)

Comment: Ok, I have done it a little differently.. I have created a partial View and Im using RenderPartial.. it works just fine except the xml comes with spaces and breaks... so it doesnt seem to work.. Im sure I have to escape the javascript but I wouldnt know how to do it with RenderPartial


myChart.setDataXML("<%Html.RenderPartial("Graph", Model.graph_data);%>"));